# Object required: 'Server' from Server.MapPath

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am in the process of converting an asp file into vbs and I am hitting a major problem

The line I am getting the error in is simple and is the first line of code

sDBName = Server.MapPath("../mydatabase.accdb")

returns

Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required 'Server'

The asp code page works fine when run as normal and I understand the need to remove "Server" from the likes of Server.CreateObject but I know that Server.MapPath should be allowed

I had another problem involving the Provider ACE.OLEDB.12.... but from this forum realised the problem was that I am using a x64 windows 2003 server.  The "cscript" fix has not helped in this instance though.

PLEASE PLEASE HELP

Dave

Answer (score 2):

The `Server` object is part of the ASP scripting environment and isn't generally available for stand-alone VBS scripts.

Also, the `MapPath()` method is used with respect to a web application's physical location on a server, and doesn't make sense for stand-alone VBS scripts.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks. Is it a case that I am incorrect and it shouldn't work at all in a vbs file?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If the Web-specific parts are important than it's probably better to keep it as an ASP script.

Comment: okay - thanks for your help - i've updated to fully resolved paths now but was just banging my head as I thought this would work.